# Is MS Graph API User Id case sensitive?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, outlook-restapi

I've been working with MS Graph API for some time now and I've been treating MS User Id in a case sensitive manner (and it worked properly). But lately I started to wonder if that is a correct approach.

I didn't find in documentation any specific mention of user id being case sensitive or case insensitive. All I found was a vague "resource id should be case sensitive". But I'm not sure if that is applicable to user id.

I'm talking about those user ids:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/user?view=graph-rest-1.0

So the question is - is user id case (in)sensitive?

Answer (score 1):

The UPN isn't case sensetive, you could try this out yourself by requesting the data for one user and changing some letters to uppercase.

Comment: I'm not asking about user principal name (UPN), I'm talking about Id. But thanks for an experiment suggestion. I've made several identical queries with user-id being lowered and uppered and results were the same. So it seems user id is case-insensitive as well.

Comment: User Id could be the UPN as well as the ObjectId from the AAD object (or "me"). None of these are case sensitive.